# Gradle Build failing after upgrading from 7.5 to 8.0 Caused by Failed to apply plugin class 'org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin'

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

A problem occurred evaluating root project

> Failed to apply plugin class 'org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin'.
> No signature of method: static org.gradle.api.plugins.internal.JvmPluginsHelper.configureDocumentationVariantWithArtifact() is applicable for argument types: (String, null, String, EmptyList, String, org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet_Decorated...) values: [sourcesElements, null, sources, [], sourceJar, main source, ...]

The [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#jvmpluginshelper) suggests to update the plugins but I am not clear on how to do that. More specifically this line is failing in build.gradle file

```
  apply plugin: 'java-library'
```

Below is the complete error log

```
Failed to apply plugin class 'org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin'.
> No signature of method: static org.gradle.api.plugins.internal.JvmPluginsHelper.configureDocumentationVariantWithArtifact() is applicable for argument types: (String, null, String, EmptyList, String, org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet_Decorated...) values: [sourcesElements, null, sources, [], sourceJar, main source, ...]
  > No signature of method: static org.gradle.api.plugins.internal.JvmPluginsHelper.configureDocumentationVariantWithArtifact() is applicable for argument types: (String, null, String, EmptyList, String, org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet_Decorated...) values: [sourcesElements, null, sources, [], sourceJar, main source, ...]
Exception
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'mantis'.  
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)   
        •••
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin class 'org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin'.    
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:173)  
        •••
    at build$_run_closure3.doCall(/home/admin123/gsoc/mantis/build.gradle:97)   
        •••
    at build.run(/home/admin123/gsoc/mantis/build.gradle:96)    
        •••
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingMethodExecutionFailed: No signature of method: static org.gradle.api.plugins.internal.JvmPluginsHelper.configureDocumentationVariantWithArtifact() is applicable for argument types: (String, null, String, EmptyList, String, org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet_Decorated...) values: [sourcesElements, null, sources, [], sourceJar, main source, ...]   
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.gradle.api.plugins.internal.JvmPluginsHelper.configureDocumentationVariantWithArtifact() is applicable for argument types: (String, null, String, EmptyList, String, org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet_Decorated...) values: [sourcesElements, null, sources, [], sourceJar, main source, ...]   
    at nebula.plugin.publishing.publications.SourceJarPlugin$_apply_closure1.doCall(SourceJarPlugin.groovy:55)  
        •••
    at build$_run_closure3.doCall(/home/admin123/gsoc/mantis/build.gradle:97)   
        •••
    at build.run(/home/admin123/gsoc/mantis/build.gradle:96)    
        •••
```

I have tried searching in documentation for relevant steps to update plugins but didn't find any. Previously, made the relevant changes to address deprecated features i.e., main and mainClassName

Comment: Have you tried the latest Gradle version `8.0.2`?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings yes